# My S3 Endpoint URL is not opening my website, why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I wrote a script that uploads all files and sub-directories of a root directory.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "My_bucket" {
  bucket = "testing-testing-testing-testing"
  tags = {
    Name = "My bucket"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "public_bucket_access" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket.bucket

  block_public_acls       = false
  block_public_policy     = false
  ignore_public_acls      = false
  restrict_public_buckets = false

  depends_on = [ aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket ]
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket.bucket

  # Terraform's "jsonencode" function converts a
  # Terraform expression's result to valid JSON syntax.
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Id      = "MYBUCKETPOLICY"
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid       = "PublicRead"
        Effect    = "Allow"
        Principal = "*"
        Action    = [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ]
        Resource = [
          "${aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket.arn}/*",
        ]
      },
    ]
  })

  depends_on = [ aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.public_bucket_access ]
}


resource "aws_s3_object" "object" {

  for_each = fileset("${path.module}/travel-agency-html-template", "**/*")

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket.bucket
  key    = basename(each.value)
  source = "${path.module}/travel-agency-html-template/${each.value}"
  etag   = filemd5("${path.module}/travel-agency-html-template/${each.value}")
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration" "travel_agency" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket.bucket

  index_document {
    suffix = "index.html"
  }

  error_document {
    key = "404.html"
  }

  depends_on = [ aws_s3_object.object ]
}
```

It does it. But when I access the endpoint URL of the website, it takes me to download a file. Instead of opening the actual website. I don't know what's wrong with my code. I'd appreciate more insights on what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: Sounds like it is not setting the correct `Content-Type` on the objects. (I'm not a Terraform person, but that might help you figure it out.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [content-type](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_object#content_type) to your objects:

```
resource "aws_s3_object" "object" {

  for_each = fileset("${path.module}/travel-agency-html-template", "**/*")

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket.bucket
  key    = basename(each.value)
  source = "${path.module}/travel-agency-html-template/${each.value}"
  etag   = filemd5("${path.module}/travel-agency-html-template/${each.value}")

  content_type = "text/html"
}
```

Depending on your files, you may need to adjust `content_type` for different files, e.g. json files would be `application/json`.

Comment: Can I also add other content types? It worked but the website is only in html. There are other content types like css, js, jpg, and php.

Comment: @charlesuneze You need to rewrite your code for other content types. Its a separate issue. Please make new question for that with the new code.

Comment: okay, done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76170291/how-do-i-specify-multiple-content-types-to-my-s3-object-using-terraform