# How do I specify multiple content types to my s3 object using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have an object resource that reads a root directory and then uploads every files and sub-directories inside the root directory.
However, the root directory contains multiple content types like js, jpg, txt, HTML, and CSS. How do I specify them in one code?

```
resource "aws_s3_object" "object" {

  for_each = fileset("${path.module}/travel-agency-html-template", "**/*")

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket.bucket
  key    = each.value
  source = "${path.module}/travel-agency-html-template/${each.value}"
  etag   = filemd5("${path.module}/travel-agency-html-template/${each.value}")

  content_type = ""

  depends_on = [ aws_s3_bucket_policy.bucket_policy ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is through `map` and `lookup` (for default value) with keys corresponding to file extensions. For example:

```
locals {
  content_type_map = {
   "js" = "application/json"
   "html" = "text/html"
   "css"  = "text/css"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "object" {

  for_each = fileset("${path.module}/travel-agency-html-template", "**/*")

  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket.bucket
  key    = each.value
  source = "${path.module}/travel-agency-html-template/${each.value}"
  etag   = filemd5("${path.module}/travel-agency-html-template/${each.value}")

  content_type = lookup(local.content_type_map, split(".", "${path.module}/travel-agency-html-template/${each.value}")[1], "text/html")

  depends_on = [ aws_s3_bucket_policy.bucket_policy ]
}
```

You haven't provided much information about your file format, thus its impossible to provide precise answer. You will have to adjust the above code to match exactly what you have.

Comment: I have created a new question providing more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76171492/i-want-to-specify-multiple-content-types-to-my-s3-object-using-terraform-how-do

Comment: @charlesuneze I already answered to of your question. Not sure what's wrong with this answer?

Comment: Omg, you were right! I just removed `${path.module}/travel-agency-html-template/` in the `content_type = lookup(local.content_type_map, split(".", "${path.module}/travel-agency-html-template/${each.value}")[1], "text/html")` and it worked!

Comment: It is likely safer and simpler to reverse the list returned by split and use the first element. This eliminates problems caused by '.' used in file names or directories. ```content_type = lookup(local.content_type_map, reverse(split(".", each.value))[0], "binary/octet-stream")```